# Probability of obtaining 2 pairs when throwing a dice 6 times

Tags: probability

I wan't to obtain the probability of obtaining 2 pairs when throwing 6 dice. For example if the throw was (1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 6) there would be two pairs (the one of 1s and the one of 3s).

The number of posible outcomes (ordered) is $6^6$.

To calculate the number of outcomes where there are two pairs I would do:

$$ \binom{6}{2} \binom{6}{1} \binom{4}{2} \binom{5}{1} \binom{4}{1} \binom{3}{1}$$

First I choose 2 from 6 for the first pair, and one dice result from the possible 6. Then I choose from the remaining 4 another 2 for the other pair, and choose a dice result for the pair from the remaining 5. Finally I choose a result for the remaining throws from 4 and 3 remaining outcomes.

When I divide the above expression by $6^6$ I don't get the correct answer.

There is something about the ordering. In $6^6$ the expression gives all the ordered possibilities, and I think I'm computing the two-pair unordered possibilities. But my result is $\frac{25}{36}$ and the correct result is $\frac{25}{72}$, so if I consider ordered posibilites my answer would be further away of the correct one.

Comment: Your mistake is the same as in [Probability of 2 pairs on 5 dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3080609/318073), you have to divide by $2$ because you double counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write favorable outcomes as $ \displaystyle \color {blue}{\binom{6}{2} \binom{6}{1} \binom{4}{2} \binom{5}{1}} \binom{4}{1} \binom{3}{1}$

The part highlighted in blue is where you are double-counting. I will name dice as $A - F$ and each dice shows a number between $1$ and $6$. Look at it this way - I first choose $2$ numbers out of $6$ possible numbers for two pairs of dice and that is $\displaystyle {6 \choose 2}$.
Now when I choose $2$ pairs of dice $ \displaystyle {6 \choose 2} {4 \choose 2}$, they are already ordered.

To explain further, say, the two chosen numbers are $1$ and $6$, and we assign $1$ to first two chosen dice and $6$ to next two chosen dice. Now say, I choose dice $A$ and $B$ first (so assign $1$ to them) and then, say, we choose dice $C$ and $D$ (so assign $6$ to them) *but* ${6 \choose 2} {4 \choose 2}$ will also count cases where I choose dice $C$ and $D$ first and then dice $A$ and $B$.

So if we are choosing two pairs of dice as $\displaystyle {6 \choose 2} {4 \choose 2}$, we should multiply it by $\displaystyle {6 \choose 2}$ instead of by $\displaystyle {6 \choose 1} {5 \choose 1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your book is considering order to be important. Here's how you can obtain the answer:
As you correctly stated, sample space is $6^6$. Now, we need to count number of favorable cases. Out of the $6$ possible outcomes, we choose $2$, which will form the $2$ pairs each. For example, if we choose $\{1,3\}$, then the pairs $11$ and $33$ will be present. This can be done in $\binom 62$ ways. Out of the $4$ outcomes left, we choose $2$ which will form the single outcomes. This is done in $\binom 42$ ways.

Now it is left to consider permutations of our choices. If we chose $\{2a,2b,c,d\}$ then our problem is equivalent to finding the number of possible words that can be formed from this. This is obviously: $\frac {6!}{2! \cdot 2!}$. This means, the number of favorable cases is:
$$N=\binom 62 \cdot \binom 42 \cdot \frac {6!}{2! \cdot 2!}$$
Thus we obtain probability $P=\frac {25}{72}$.